# Tracking Android device in space using device camera

Tags: android, firebase, augmented-reality, arcore, google-mlkit

I am looking to get device position (x, y, and z) in space in the most efficient way possible. Currently I am using ArSceneView (ArCore) to get the cameras pose as it updates.

The problem is that ArSceneView or the class it extends from seems to have a memory leak that eventually crash my app. I have tried forcing garbage collection and increasing the heap size but the app is still crashing.

I do not need view to display the camera stream so a class with a view is not necessary, I just need a way to get the mobiles x y and z coordinates. Does anyone know of a way to get these using MLKit or pure ArCore (no view)?

Side note: my app does not crash when the android studio profiler is on... anyone know why?

**WHERE I START AND STOP AR MODULE:**

```
public void initializeSession() {
    if (sessionInitializationFailed) {
        return;
    }
    UnavailableException sessionException;
    try {
        session = new Session(context);
        Config config = new Config(session);
        config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        setupSession(session);
        session.configure(config);
        return;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        sessionException = new UnavailableException();
        sessionException.initCause(e);
    }
    sessionInitializationFailed = true;
}

void start() {
    System.gc();
    if (isStarted) {
        return;
    }

    isStarted = true;
    try {
        initializeSession();
        this.resume();
    } catch (CameraNotAvailableException ex) {
        sessionInitializationFailed = true;
    }

}

void stop() {
    if (!isStarted) {
        return;
    }

    isStarted = false;
    this.pause();
    this.stop();
    System.gc();
}
```

**WHERE I LISTEN FOR CHANGES:**

```
public void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {
    if (arModule == null) {
        return;
    }
    Frame frame = arModule.getArFrame();
    if (frame == null) {
        return;
    }

    Camera camera = frame.getCamera();
    Pose pose = camera.getPose();
    TrackingState trackingState = camera.getTrackingState();

    if (trackingState == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        float x = pose.tx();
        float y = pose.ty();
        float z = pose.tz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it comes out of getPose() but make sure you have the right thing before the .getPose because there are at least two ways and one of them is bad. I don't recall off the top of my head, but just search above on "getPose" and you will see explanations...

Comment: I can get accurate results with my current set up but the library crashes after a while... Thats why Im trying to find an alternative way to do this.

Comment: If you post some of the code that crashes then I could let you know how it differs from mine...

Comment: Just added my code, thanks for looking into this!

Comment: It looks like you are doing the getCamera twice but you got the getPose from the first getCamera and are using it after the the second getCamera. You cannot expect object-oriented languages to protect you from things like that...

Comment: Ive updated it but it does not make a difference. Hopefully someone knows of a way that does not use ArSceneView

Comment: All I can suggest is that you take the official example code arcore-android-sdk-1.23.0/samples/hello_ar_java and put in your few lines of code like .tx() and so forth using their namespace. Next, gut-out all the things you don't need, then pile your app on top of that...

Comment: I did try using the hello_ar code example and I did strip the code down to see if I could find out what they're doing but their configuration is different. I need to get the camera pose from the latest frame as they update, I think its just an issue with ArSceneView 17

Comment: If you are not trying to force their code to do something they did not intend it to do, then file a bug report with them and let us know what it is...

Answer (score 0):

In the [HelloAR sample app](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/hello_ar_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java#L613), you can clearly see that they are getting the pose of the camera. Their app does not crash, so it is not a bug. It's hard to tell from your code whether you are getting a memory leak somewhere else. Just add the bit about storing camera pose inside the HelloAR sample app.

Comment: their app does crash the same way after 5-7 min of walking around with arsceneview running, I have also tested not storing the camera pose to see if the crash is on my end and the crash still happens. You have to move around for the crash to happen, if you let the phone sit the tracking can go on for almost an hr.

Comment: What does the log say when the app crashes?

Comment: Points to an exception thrown in RenderableData.java of com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering in line 228 when the renderableInstance == 0